# The angle between two vectors remain the same after the parallel translation and Riemannian connection.

Tags: riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold, $\nabla$ be a symmetric affine connection, prove:
If the angle between two vectors remain the same after the parallel translation along any curve, then $\nabla$ is a Riemannian connection. 
 
I have tried choosing an orthonormal basis of $p\in M$, but parallel translation doesn't keep the scale of the vectors, thus the scales of basis can't remain the same, as a result we can't use the classical method described in Do Carmo's book. So can someone provide a solution to this problem?
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because the angle is keep. You  have a orthogonal extend. Then normal them. You can do same thing likely to 3.2 Proposition (53th page) of Do Carmo's book.

Comment: @lanse7pty Yeah, after some efforts, I think your comment is indeed reasonable, thanks!